# Problem with installing Lubuntu via USB on an Acer Aspire one ZG5

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu, system-installation, acer

I tried installing Lubuntu on an Acer Aspire ZG5 via an bootable USB I made with UNetbootin. Last night I was able to boot up without installing. Today i tried to boot up again and the screen says boot aborted. When I try to boot up normally the computer doesn't boot and it makes a loud beeping sound.

What did I do wrong? Do i need to make a new bootable USB? try another distro?

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your pendrive and making a new bootable pendrive using Unetbootin. Or Just to be extra sure why don't you try using another software like rufus, etc. and see if the problem persists.